# How to get Dynamic URL through HTACCESS file in PHP?

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic-url

I need to use dynamic sub domain in the url.
My PHP application will open account for users.

My URL for login screen will be

```
http://example.dev/app/login
```

After logging in, user will go to the following section

```
http://example.dev/app/section/account_name=ram
```

My current domain is example.dev

My requirement is to bring account name in the domain name. My URL should be like the  following

```
http://ram.exmaple.dev/app/section
```

Similarly, if my account name is sundar means , my URL should be like this

```
http://sundar.example.dev/app/section
```

I know this is possible using .HTACCESS. I tried this but I am not able to get it correctly

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z-]+).example.dev$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)$ /app/section/?account_name=%1[QSA]

Is the above is correct?

Important Point: 
At the end of htaccess, I have to call one controller file.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example_controller.php

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want no cahnge in example_controller.php at all.

PHP accesses the original URL with: **$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]** it will contain the original request address, not the "last but one" request address.

The only solution I can think of is a reverse proxy. You can use *.htaccess* to create proxy requests (with the [P] directive) to your own host to the desired URL. This way PHP will see that URL as **REDIRECT_URL** because that is an original URL of a request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z-]+).example.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.dev/app/section/?account_name=%1[PQSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example_controller.php
```

You have to have mod_proxy enabled of course. I'm not sure how P and QSA directives work togather, give it a try.

Comment: can you give me example for this proxy requests?

Comment: Yep, i added one (not tested though).